# WPF: How to make a textbox dynamically sized yet prevent autosizing?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, layout

I know there are a lot of questions in regard to the auto sizing of text boxes in WPF, but I couldn't find a solution for the following problem.

Consider this simple window:

```
<Window x:Class="TestVisualBrush.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="470" Width="608">
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox>Test</TextBox>
        <TextBox MinHeight="100" Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True" >Test</TextBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

This implements these two constraints I need:

1. This setup will make the second text box sized dynamically so that it uses the remaining window space.
2. If the window becomes too small for the required minimum size of the `ScrollViewer`'s contents, the `ScrollViewer` shows a scrollbar.

However, when you type too much text in the second text box, the `ScrollViewer` shows a scrollbar, instead of the `TextBox`. I'd like to stop the text box from increasing its height beyond the space given by the parent `Grid` originally. I can't use `MaxHeight` in this case because there is no suitable `ActualHeight` to bind to (as far as I can see).

Any suggestions on how to solve this (preferably without code-behind)?

[image: Note that the root ScrollViewer should still scroll if its contents are too large for the window.]

In HTML what I want would translate to this:

```
<table height="100%">
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="100%"> 
    <td>
          <!-- Uses as much space as it gets, but scrolls if text inside
               gets too large. Makes outer window scroll if too small
               for min-height and other controls in table. -->
      <textarea style="height:100%;min-height:100px"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To clear it up: You want a textbox with minSize = 100px (if the window is smaller show scrollbar) and maxSize = 100% remeining Size in parentWindow (If the content is too big, the textbox should show a scrollbar, but not the whole window) ... If this is what you want, one solution would be to set the maxSize of the Textbox on WindowResize or Grid Relayouting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scrollable-expandable-controls problem.

Scrollable-expandable-controls : are controls that can stretch as its content grows and will display scrollbars when their size is restricted.

Problem appears when they are located inside another scrollable control. Child scrollable-expandable-controls will keep expanding and will count on the outer scrollable control's scrollbars.

if you give it a maximum width or height problem will be resolved but you will need to know the size ahead and you don't have this privilege if you want a dynamic app that works well with all different screen sizes.

in order to achieve required behavior , we need a panel in between to allow its children (scrollable-expandable-control) to grow asking them to give the minimum required size and then give them the maxiumum size the parent provides without displaying scrollbars , currently there is no panel like this.

Here is a one that I developed to provide this functionality:

```
    class LimitChild : System.Windows.Controls.Panel
    {
        public LimitChild()
        {
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(InternalChildren.Count == 1);
            System.Windows.UIElement child = InternalChildren[0];

            Size panelDesiredSize = new Size();
            // panelDesiredSize.Width = availableSize.Width;
            panelDesiredSize.Width = (double)child.GetValue(FrameworkElement.MinWidthProperty);
            panelDesiredSize.Height = (double)child.GetValue(FrameworkElement.MinHeightProperty);

            child.Measure(panelDesiredSize);

            // IMPORTANT: do not allow PositiveInfinity to be returned, that will raise an exception in the caller! 
            // PositiveInfinity might be an availableSize input; this means that the parent does not care about sizing 
            return panelDesiredSize;
        }

        protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size finalSize)
        {
            System.Windows.UIElement child = InternalChildren[0];

            child.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height));
            if (finalSize.Width > child.RenderSize.Width)
                finalSize.Width = child.RenderSize.Width;
            if (finalSize.Height > child.RenderSize.Height)
                finalSize.Height = child.RenderSize.Height;

            return finalSize; // Returns the final Arranged size
        }
    }
```

and then inside your xaml incapsulate your scrollable-expandable-control in it.

```
        <l:LimitChild
            Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                MinHeight="200"
                AcceptsReturn="True">Test</TextBox>
        </l:LimitChild>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but the textbox still expands the parent ScrollViewer.

Comment: Just tried your code again (sort of last-minute) and it does in fact seem to work now. Not sure what I did wrong the first time, maybe I still had some leftovers from previous experiments.

Comment: Still I don't feel that this is the best solution. I will keep working on it. But of course , I blame Microsoft they should have created better way to layout controls in scrollable panels.

Comment: Why not? I think having a new Control class is a neat solution and requires very few XAML.

Comment: because 
1) I will have to surround each multi-line textbox with a panel.
2) and sometimes my multi-line textbox exist in another composite control.

Comment: OK, that's not a problem for me though since I only have very few select cases where I need this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This should exactly meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not helping with constraint 2). I need the whole window contents to scroll if the stuff inside the Grid exceed the available window space. For example I had MinHeight=100 for the textbox, it must not get too small and if the window is not large enough to hold two text boxes (one being 100px high) the entire window must scroll its contents, so I need the outer ScrollViewer.

Comment: OK, so for clarification: there shall be 3 possible states? 1. The window is too small to hold the text boxes in their minimum height but the Content in the second text box does not exceed its minimum height, then you want to see the outer ScrollViewer. 2. The Window is large enough, then you want to see the ScrollViewer within the TextBox only if it's content exceeds its possible height. 3. The window is too small to hold the text boxes in their minimum height and the content in the second text box exceeds its minimum height -> you want to see both ScrollViewers?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can bind to `ActualHeight` by accessing ancestor using [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) binding:

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},
                 Path=RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight}"
```

---

*Update:*

If you what that scroll bar should be shown only for *second* `TextBox` - put `ScrollViewer` *only* for it:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox>Test</TextBox>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">                
            <TextBox MinHeight="100" AcceptsReturn="True" >Test</TextBox>                
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't quite do what I need either, it doesn't match the first constraint I mentioned. If I add your code and you reduce the window size, a scrollbar appears immediately (and it doesn't increase its size if the window gets enlarged).

Comment: What would the converter do exactly?

Comment: @floele Adjust height.

Comment: @floele Just tried your code and it works without hiding `TextBox`. Cat you add screenshots. It might help.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Note that the root ScrollViewer should still scroll if the window size is too small for its contents.

Comment: Nope, this is not what I want. If I do this, 2) is violated. I need an "outer" scroll bar that scrolls all elements that don't fit into the window space.

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza RowDefinition's `ActualHeight` is not dependency property so changes will not affect the bound property (unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Height="50"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

    </Grid>
```

And you are done :)

Comment: Heh, that seems a bit like cheating ;) Well, your solution is pretty close, but if you wrap a ScrollViever around the textbox, the top/bottom borders of the textbox will disappear when you scroll it. Doesn't look nice.

Comment: @floele : Hey its not cheating, we call it work around ;)..!! And I didn't get your point. Can you please give a screen dump or any additional information for point you mentioned..?

Comment: OK, check this: http://i60.tinypic.com/2vdkyub.jpg Scrolled to bottom, top border gone. This is why I think we need sort of an "inner" scrollviewer instead of your "workaround" ;)

Comment: @floele See edit. I hope you will like it and award me a bounty ;) and now I am not cheating at all :D

Comment: Hm, strange. This seems to work, but it's so simple I'm almost sure I already tried that without success. Will do some more testing and let you know.

Comment: Ah no actually it doesn't work. Don't forget to wrap the outer ScrollViewer around your Grid. Because if you do, the outer ScrollViewer will show the scrollbar when you enter too much text instead of showing the scrollbar of the textbox (looks like my "actual" screenshot from above).

Comment: Okey, I think what you want is not possible and it shouldn't be allowed too. If grid have a scroll viewer and two text boxes in it, Both the text boxes will always have space to accommodate their content. Textbox will never get inner scroll in such situation.

Comment: Of course it should be allowed. If HTML can do it, why not WPF? ;) I still need to check Ashi's answer.

Comment: Okey..! Hope you will get what you want..else you will always have work around ..!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the line you have to set the max height of the scroll enabled text box. Normally * would do that but because it is wrapped in a scroll viewer the containing grid has no effective maximum. 
You could use a MultiValueConverter like this

```
    public class MaxHeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double result = (double)values[0];
        for (int n = 1; n < values.Length; ++n)
        {
            result = result - (double)values[n];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then your XAML will look like this

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_Hacks.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_Hacks"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MaxHeightConverter x:Key="maxHeightConverter"></local:MaxHeightConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="headerTextBox" Height="50" Text="Textbox 1"/>

        <TextBox MinHeight="100" Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="Textbox 2">
            <TextBox.MaxHeight>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource maxHeightConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="rootGrid" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="headerTextBox" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.MaxHeight>
        </TextBox>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Basically the multi value converter takes the first bound value as the total height available and then reduces this by the heights of the other bound elements leaving the remaining space for the final textbox

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't apply this solution because in the real world example the Grid contains many more controls. Adding all these to the MultiBinding is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something like this, however i'm still testing, just need to know if this is what you imagined?

```
<Window x:Class="testWpf.WindowTextBoxInnerScroll"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="608" Name="MyWindow" Loaded="MyWindow_Loaded">

<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
<Grid name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox>Test</TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="TB2" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" >Test</TextBox>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code behind

```
private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.Height > MyGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight + MyGrid.RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight)
  {
    TB2.Height = MyGrid.RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight;
  }
  else
  {
    TB2.Height = TB2.MinHeight;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If this is not what you want, then I'm uncertain of what your expectations to this question are.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE 2**

I've updated my XAML and Code behind, this is working for me. (I think).

Comment: In theory it is, but putting the TextBox in a ScrollViewer will result in the TextBox borders disappearing when scrolling. 
Naresh Ravlani suggested the same before.

Comment: true, but fact is you have no control over the inner scrollviewer/scrollbar if it's already in a scrollviewer.. Or so it seems. and wouldn't it be possible just to margin the textbox with 1 all around if the border is all you want? Oh, and i've just tested, my textbox borders stays visible :P

Comment: "wouldn't it be possible just to margin the textbox with 1" - what do you mean? I dn't quite understand.

Comment: Well sounded like you said your borders dissapeared behind the scrollviewer or so, so if you margined the textbox inside the scrollviewer, all your borders would be visible again. etc: Margin="1" on the textbox.. Again I working out different possibilities without knowing the end result :p

Comment: Nope, if you scroll the textbox down, the border of it mst eventually disappear. Margins don't help here.

Comment: I see. Have you looked up something like binding to RowDefinition height?

Comment: I'm currently experiementing with Ashi's solution. It seems to be the cleanest approach and I believe it can be made to work actually.

Comment: What I couldn't achieve in XAML I think i achieved in Code behind. With not to much code. I'll update my example.

Comment: That will not work if you resize the window though I suppose.

Comment: No it will not. but then you might wanna do something on SizeChanged event, or find a equvilant reset the height of the textbox :P

Comment: Seems to be a lot of fuss, in no way better than Ashi's solution. Sry ;)